# Когда запускаю webpack такая ошибка выводится. В чем может проблема?

Tags: webpack, babel

```
loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string value which can be problematic, see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56
parseQuery() will be replaced with getOptions() in the next major version of loader-utils.
Hash: 7782cb475ac2e7a51788
Version: webpack 2.4.1
Time: 771ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  2.95 kB       0  [emitted]  main


/--------------------------------------------------------/
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output:{
        path: "/src/js",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/src/js",
    },
    devServer:{
        inline: true,
        contentBase: "./src",
        port: 3000,
    },
    module:{
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["latest","stage-0", "react"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что во второй версии вебпака объявили устаревшими некоторые штуки которые использовали разработчики загрузчиков (https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56). В том числе эти штуки использовал и babel-loader, который у вас в конфиге есть

1. Оно пока работает. Это просто warning а не ужасная ошибка.
2. Фикс для babel-loader есть, но в совершенно новой версии, которая пока в бете, а не в хотфиксе существующей. (Источник: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/pull/391).

Так что традиционно для bleeding edge инструментов, либо ждать, либо фиксить самому, либо забить на новые суперфичи и жить со старой стабильной версией вебпака.